# Meaning of "And held the darkness over day, that night"

Tags: sentence-meaning, poetry

I don't understand the meaning of above line. It's from the song Valentine's Day by Linkin Park. I've posted the full verse below:

> My insides all turned to ash, so slow
> And blew away as I collapsed, so cold
> A black wind took them away, from sight
> **And held the darkness over day, that night**

So does the above line mean "the night is dark" or "the day is so dark that it looks like night". Also feel free to point out any grammatical error in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of "that night" seems to suggest that something has happened at night, so that rules out interpreting this verse as "the day being so dark that it looks like night".

The first interpretation (that "the night is dark") could be correct - the black wind holds the darkness over the day, preventing the day from happening.

But that would be a rather literal reading of what's probably intended to be a metaphor - "darkness" is often associated with negative feelings and emotions and "day/light" with positive ones, and I think the author intended to express the sadness they felt rather than how dark it was outside the window. So my reading of the line would be "that night, something made me feel sad and suppressed my positive feelings".